# can ubuntustudio compose music (e.g. play guitar then auto write notation note)

Tags: music, ubuntu-studio

can ubuntustudio software can compose music(e.g. play guitar via audio input then auto write notation note)?  Or is there any software can compose music in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You may compose with **Tuxguitar** and **MuseScore** for example, but these are for writing notation, then playing them as MIDI. However you have to write the notation yourself, they won't do it for you.

For guitars I recommend Tuxgitar because it has tablatures, but for everything else I recommend MuseScore.

Both software is readily available in Ubuntu, you just have to install it through the package manager.